# Checking column values in python panda

Tags: python, pandas

How do I check whether the column values in a panda table are the same and create the result in a fourth column:

original

```
    red  blue  green
a   1    1     1
b   1    2     1
c   2    2     2
```

becomes:

```
   red blue green match
a  1   1    1     1
b  1   2    1     0
c  2   2    2     1
```

Originally I only had 2 columns and it was possible to achieve something similar by doing this:

```
df['match']=df['blue']-df['red']
```

but this won't work with 3 columns.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more generic, compare row values on apply method.

Using `set()`

```
In [54]: df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1, axis=1).astype(int)

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
   red  blue  green  match
a    1     1      1      1
b    1     2      1      0
c    2     2      2      1
```

Alternatively, use `pd.Series.nunique` to identify number of unique in row.

```
In [56]: (df.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1) == 1).astype(int)
Out[56]:
a    1
b    0
c    1
dtype: int32
```

Or, use `df.iloc[:, 0]` for first column values and match it `eq` with `df`

```
In [57]: df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1).astype(int)
Out[57]:
a    1
b    0
c    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: if I wanted a '0' where there is a match and '1' where is no match, can I just change `len(set(x))==1` to `len(set(x))==0`?

Comment: `len(set(x)) != 1` would be more appropriate, I think?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df["match"] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]==x[1]==x[2]), axis=1)
```

where:

- `x[0]==x[1]==x[2]` : test for the eaquality of the 3 first columns
- `axis=1`: columns wise

Alternatively, you can call the column by their name too:

```
df["match"] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x["red"]==x["blue"]==x["green"]), axis=1)
```

This is more convenient if you have many column and that you want to compare a subpart of them without knowing their number.

If you want to compare all the columns, use John Galt's solution